# Data Repository Pattern Design C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, design-patterns, repository

I have an entity class

```
public partial class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

and this entity

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Tokens = new HashSet<Token>();
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Token> Tokens { get; set; }
}
```

I have a repository pattern

```
public abstract class DataRepositoryBase<T> : IDataRepository<T>
       where T : class, new()
{
        protected abstract T AddEntity(T entity);

        protected abstract T UpdateEntity(T entity);

        protected abstract IEnumerable<T> GetEntities();

        protected abstract T GetEntity(int id);
}
```

How can I call repository using generic data repository using some thing like `this.<T>` just using generic interface not creating new class? Thanks.

```
_datarepositorypattern.GetDataRepository<IProductRepository>();
_datarepositorypattern.GetDataRepository<IUserRepository>();
```

what i want, somthing like this.

```
var obj = _datarepositorypattern.GetDataRepository<IDataRepository<User>>(); 

//then i can access use
obj.GetEntities();
```

**update**
I already created repository 
this repository can return

```
public DataRepositoryBase<Product> ProductRepository => new ProductRepository();
```

in the service class

```
        private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        public ProductServices(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }



    Product[] IProductServices.GetProduct()
    {
        var repository = _unitOfWork.ProductRepository;

        return repository.Get().ToArray();
    }
```

i use this current repository method like this.

what i wanted create dynamic repository so i do not updating my repository again only updating my service class with code like this.

```
var obj = _datarepositorypattern.GetDataRepository<IProductRepository>(); 
obj.GetEntities();
```

just using repository repository pattern i can get dynamic repository product

```
var obj = _datarepositorypattern.GetDataRepository<IUserRepository>(); 
obj.GetEntities();
```

just using repository repository pattern i can get dynamic repository User.

**UPDATE**
I just googling this is an repositoryfactorypattern can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

as you've written it here you need you need new classes. You specify the IProductRepository and IUserRepository

that means you need something like

```
class UserRepository : DataRepositoryBase<User>, IUserRepository
{
  //userrepository code here
}
```

otherwise you would get something like

```
_datarepositorypattern.GetDataRepository<IDataRepository<User>>();
```

expecially since your datarepository class is abstract you need a concrete implementation somewhere

**Update:** example not using entity specific repositories

If you really want to avoid entity specific repositories you can look at breeze.

you still need something like theis

```
class MyContext : DbContext {
    DbSet<Product> Products {get; set;}
    DBSet<User> Users {get; set;}
}
```

but then you can call a context provider like this

```
public class DataRepositoryBase<T> : IDataRepository<T> {
    readonly EFContextProvider<User> _contextProvider =
        new EFContextProvider<User>();


    public void SaveEntity(JObject saveBundle) {
       _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    }

}
```

now you can just call new DataBaseObjectRepository() (or have that code in your GetDataRepository method)

maybe that is a place to start. You do need something like DbContext that tells you how to map different types to different tables.

Comment: no, what i want, somthing like this. var obj = _datarepositorypattern.GetDataRepository<IDataRepository<User>>(); and i can use obj.addEntity or some thing like that.

Comment: added some breeze example. maybe that helps

Comment: perhaps you can show me how to get this _datarepositorypattern.GetDataRepository<IDataRepository<User>>();, with this maybe i can thing of something. thanks.

Comment: i hope it's clear now. make DataRespository non-abstract and use breeze contextProvider to implement your methods.

Comment: it's not working i need the class still abstracted. because i need it.

Comment: i already added more of update in my project.. please review it.. i am sory if it not so clear.. but please help me.